# Defining projection in arc toolbox (JSON to shapefile) in python

Tags: python, arcpy, arctoolbox, json

I have a arc toolbox which converts JSON txt file to a shapefile but we have to define the projection.

How can I hard code the defined projection so that user don't have to input the projection ?

I need to define projection parameter to web mercator and to add a function to reproject the shapefile to NAD 83 UTM.

I am editing in Python.

Comment: How do I put the code in here?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Define Projection (Data Management) [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000)...

> This tool overwrites the coordinate system information (map projection
>   and datum) stored with a dataset.

---

> Syntax
>
> DefineProjection_management (in_dataset, coor_system)

Example Code:

```
# Name: DefineProjection.py 
# Description: Records the coordinate system information for the specified input
dataset or feature class
# Author: ESRI

# import system modules
import arcpy

# set workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"

# set local variables
inDataset = "forest.shp"
coordinateSystem = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',
                   SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],
                   PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"

arcpy.DefineProjection_management(inDataset, coordinateSystem)
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Can I do it by defining Spatial reference, if so how?